# Simple problem with function type hinting in Pycharm,

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Is it normal that when I am trying to automatically add hint to this function:

```
def foo(x: int) :
    return x
```

I get:

```
def foo(x: int)  -> object:
    return x
```

In the documentation window it is done correctly:

```
def foo(x: int)  -> int:
    return x
```

Why Pycharm cannot automatize this?
Is there any way to do it like I want?

Comment: I mean, it's not *wrong* (`foo` does return a value of type `object`), it's just not as specific as it could be. It appears it's not trying to analyze the body of `foo` to see what the return type could be, only the (empty) context in which return values of `foo` are used. What happens if you add a line of code like `y: int = foo(3)`, does that let it infer that `foo` is supposed to return an `int`? What if you have `y: str = foo(3)`, does that generate any errors, or does it naively assume that `foo` will return a `str`?

Comment: (If you can't tell, I don't use Pycharm, and it's not clear from the documentation exactly *how* the automated type-hinting proceeds.)

Comment: Honestly, at some point you might as well just ask why PyCharm doesn't write the code for you too.

Answer (score 0):

"Add type hints" intention action doesn't use type inference to suggest the specific type. The corresponding feature request in PyCharm's issue tracker: [PY-28733](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28733/Intention-Add-type-hints-for-function-should-allow-to-use-inferred-types-in-addition-to-those-collected-by-debugger).

The idea itself is quite reasonable, in my opinion. It just didn't get enough traction to be implemented. Please vote for the ticket, if you would like to have such functionality available.